# useEffect does not get triggered when a dependence value changes from 1 to 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm so confused about the behaviour of **useEffect** in the following case:

**Code snippet**:

```
const verticesCount = selectionProvider.verticesSelectionProvider.count;
console.log('RENDER ---> COUNT = ', verticesCount);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('EFFECT : COUNT UPDATED ---> COUNT = ', verticesCount);

    return () => console.log('USEEFFECT:CLEANUP');
}, [verticesCount]);
```

**The console**:

```
1: RENDER ---> COUNT =  0 
2: EFFECT : COUNT UPDATED ---> COUNT =  0
3: RENDER ---> COUNT =  1
4: USEEFFECT:CLEANUP
5: EFFECT : COUNT UPDATED ---> COUNT =  1
6: RENDER ---> COUNT =  0
```

Comment: Can you please share a [mre] of this issue so we can help debug?

Answer (score 0):

Without a better example it is difficult to tell what is the problem.

My guess is that `verticesCount`  didn't change.

For example verticesCount was: 1, changed to 2, changed to 1, then changed one more time to 1

But because the state value didn't change the last time the useEffect didn't trigger.
One possible solution:

- create a bool state: `const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);`
- in your `verticesSelectionProvider` toggle `setUpdate(!update)` every time vertices changed
- in `useEffect()` listen for `update` instead of `verticesCount`